# ExecutionEngineException thrown when calling native code

Tags: c, vb.net, pinvoke, executionengineexception

I have a function that is exported by a C library with the following signature:

`extern "C" BOOL Func()`

The function is declared in VB.NET code like this:

`<DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>`

`Private Shared Function Func() As Boolean`

`End Function`

The problem is that I get an ExecutionEngineException when I call the function from .NET code.

Given that `BOOL` is typedef'd as `int` in this C code, should the declaration be different? If so, how should I be declaring this? As `Short` or `Int32`? Do I need to marshal the return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C function doesn't return a true boolean, it returns an integer. You might need to [marshall it propery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx).

Edit: Also, you should make your function static.

Comment: Does this mean I need to do this: Private Shared Function Func() As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean

Comment: Yes.  But that's not your problem, the unmanaged code is destroying the heap.

Comment: Hi Hans, are you talking about the managed heap when you say 'the unamaged code is destroying the heap'? What can I do to avoid this? What should I be looking for in the unmanaged code? As far as I can tell, it does not seem to be doing anything destructive, like allocating and destroying arrays.

Comment: As it turned out, the fix was to marshal it the way I did in my first comment.

Comment: Excellent. Thought that might be the case :)